# Not even a single product is displayed at frontend

Tags: product

The database is migrated to  server.Still the theme is not yet uploaded to the server and currently the site is in rwd/default.Now the categories are showing up but products are not showing up at the frontend(List & details page) and the attributes are not showing up inside the attribute sets at backend.What should be done?

Comment: do re-index and cache after open product in admin

Comment: yea cache cleared and reindexed.  no change

Comment: At least it is showing categories on front end.check one product website and category mapping ,inventory

Answer (score 1):

You have to update all product manually using admin panel.
First go to admin panel,

Go To,

```
 Catalog -> Manage Products,
```

Select all product, go to `action dropdown`, select `change status` , select `status as enable` and click submit button.

Now clear cache and reindexing,
Your problem is solved.

Thanks.

Comment: if answer is helpful, plz accept this answer to another community users to helpful

Comment: All the products are already enabled.

Comment: but you have to do for all products and check, sometimes database will need to update. so just submit.

Comment: Have you try using this way?, plz try and check its working.

Comment: YEa I tried but its not working

Comment: you have try using all product submit and reindexing?

Comment: yea tried reindexing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35029/discussion-between-ramya-and-rakesh-jesadiya).

Answer (score 0):

Check if products have a check sign in front of a category in Admin - to which category they fit. Also, check the url of some specific product and try copying that url to the browser, is product showing?

Comment: Yea I've checked. I think It is a database import problem. Anyway Thank you for guidance